# How to retrieve File in a .JAR project

Tags: java, file, inputstream, executable-jar

I am pretty new to java and made a new project with JFrames and JPanels to create a clock display to tell the time, date, and days. now when I package the project into a JAR executable and run it, I get hit with an exception, and don't know how to track what/where the exception is. I looked into it and found how I got resources (files), from my source code was incorrect. My way to get the file was: "File {insert var name} = new File(projectname...\src\Assets\Cozy.ttf"), which is just a font for the JPanels to use. The more I kept reading into alternatives like "getResourceAsStream()", and "getResource()", the more I got stuck. I don't know where to start because I haven't worked with files on this level. I read about "File.createTempFile()", but it all seems very confusing. And I cant find any simplistic and effective documentation for what I need.

The main problem I have is that I can't load File objects from inside the .JAR. I know I'm not being descriptive or this isn't very helpful without any code, but I don't really know what to do now.

I tried to research into Class.getResourceAsStream(), and had mild success with retreiving the designated object without problems, but then the whole thing became a little useless when I looked into converting the InputStream into a File and got nothing that was really easy to wrap my head around.

I also don't know if I could use the raw InputStream into the Font object for Font.createFont(truetypeConstant,InputStream) to be a valid syntax.

Comment: If it's a file it isn't in the JAR. If it's in the JAR it isn't a file. Why do you think you need a `File` when you can get an `InputStream` directly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`File` is literal. As in, it represents files, and 'things in a jar file' **are not files**. Hence, what you want is impossible short of unpacking that stuff. More generally if `src` is anywhere in a hardcoded path, that's not going to work.

The solution is resource loading:

```
public class ThisIsAnExample {
  public void setIconExample() {
    JLabel label = ...;
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ThisIsAnExample.class.getResource("myIcon.png")));
  }
}
```

Usage notes:

- The path is relative to the class file. In your jar, somewhere, there's `ThisIsAnExample.class`. In the same place (same dir), put `myIcon.png`.
- Maven automatically moves stuff from `/src/main/resources` into the jar. If you use a different build system, figure out where to put non-java files so they are included. If you're writing it yourself, copy them into the jar.
- You can use `/myIcon.png` to be relative to the root of the jar.
- If you're confused about where it's looking, print `MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class")` - class files are resources just the same, you can ask for it.
- `getResource` returns a URL which many things in swing allow, so, use that. If not, though, there's `getResourceAsStream` which will require `try () {}` to safely use, then, you have an input stream you can read from.
- You can open the contents of entries in the jar. **You cannot list jar contents**. Use SPI if you need that.
- Don't call `.getClassLoader()`, and don't call `.getClass()`. It's `MyClassName.class.getResource` (or `getResourceAsStream`). They don't make things better, and there are cases where those alternatives break where `MyClass.class.getResource` does not.
- `jar tvf myjar.jar` shows you the jar structure.

Comment: So when I tried to use 
prefabFormat.class.getResourceAsStream("Assets\\Cozy.ttf");

then I got the exception error: 

 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1208)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1076)
        at ClockWorkWindow.prefabFormat.<init>(prefabFormat.java:32)
        at ClockWorkWindow.mainDriver.main(mainDriver.java:41)'

Comment: @KitchenSpice It’s `"Assets/Cozy.ttf"`.  The string argument is actually a relative URL, not a filename, so the argument must use forward-slash (`/`) on all platforms.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I just finished compiling and all of the code runs flawlessly. I can't tell you how much this has helped me.